# Initialize array without zeroes

Tags: arrays, matlab, initialization, zero

I have an 3 dimensional array that represents an xy grid, and the z vector represents depth. I only know depths of certain rows and am trying to interpolate the array. My questions is how do I create a 720x400 array, without setting all the values to 0 (as that could affect the interpolation).

Thanks!

Comment: This is not at all clear.  If you don't want to initialise the values to 0, then what do you want to initialise them to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to initialize the empty rows to a special value. Instead, you can modify the interpolation procedure to assign a zero weight to these rows. Then, they will not affect the interpolation.

A simple way to do so in MATLAB would be to use the griddata method for the interpolation.

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
A = nan(m,n,...);
```

to initialize a matrix with `NaN's`, if that is what you ask for. Other popular choices are `inf(m,n,...)` to initialize with `Inf's` and `ones(m,n,...)` to initialize with `1's`.

So, to create a 720x400 matrix full of `NaN's` you can just:

```
A = nan(720,400);
```